# UPSERT in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, upsert

I am writing an SSIS package to run on SQL Server 2008. How do you do an UPSERT in SSIS?

```
IF KEY NOT EXISTS
  INSERT
ELSE
  IF DATA CHANGED
    UPDATE
  ENDIF
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [SQL Server 2008 - Using Merge From SSIS](http://agilebi.com/cs/blogs/jwelch/archive/2007/07/05/sql-server-2008-using-merge-from-ssis.aspx#86). I've implemented something like this, and it was very easy. Just using the BOL page [Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data using MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx) was enough to get me going.

Comment: I confirm, MERGE is the way to go. Read it on Kimball here : http://www.kimballgroup.com/html/08dt/KU107_UsingSQL_MERGESlowlyChangingDimension.pdf

Comment: The kimballgroup link is dead.

Comment: SQL Server's MERGE has had (still has?) more bugs than just about anything in SQL Server. For instance, it gives the impression that it is transactionally consistent. It is not!

Comment: @Mitch I never got the impression it was transactionally consistent. I never assume anything is, unless it explicitly says so.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: many people have been caught by assuming this, even experts.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from T-SQL based solutions (and this is not even tagged as [sql](/questions/tagged/sql)/[tsql](/questions/tagged/tsql)), you can use an SSIS Data Flow Task with a Merge Join as described [here](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/150-Insert,-Update,-and-Delete-Destination-table-with-SSIS.html) (and [elsewhere](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5082/synchronize-table-data-using-a-merge-join-in-ssis/)).

[image]

The crucial part is the Full Outer Join in the Merger Join (if you only want to insert/update and not delete a Left Outer Join works as well) of your sorted sources.

[image]

followed by a Conditional Split to know what to do next: Insert into the destination (which is also my source here), update it  (via SQL Command), or delete from it (again via SQL Command).

1. INSERT: If the gid is found only on the source (left)
2. UPDATE If the gid exists on both the source and destination
3. DELETE: If the gid is not found in the source but exists in the destination (right)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to have a look at Mat Stephen's weblog on SQL Server's upsert.

[SQL 2005 - UPSERT: In nature but not by name; but at last!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mat_stephen/sql-2005-upsert-in-nature-but-not-by-name-but-at-last)

Comment: Tx for that. Is there an SSIS equivalent for the T-SQL commands? A walk-through would be very useful. (noob)

Comment: The link appears dead.  Try http://blogs.technet.com/mat_stephen/archive/2005/08/31/410022.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The basic Data Manipulation Language (DML) commands that have been in use over the years are Update, Insert and Delete. They do exactly what you expect: Insert adds new records, Update modifies existing records and Delete removes records.

UPSERT statement modifies existing records, if a records is not present it INSERTS new records.
The functionality of UPSERT statment can be acheived by two new set of TSQL operators. These are the two new ones

```
EXCEPT
INTERSECT
```

**Except:-**

Returns any distinct values from the query to the left of the EXCEPT operand that are not also returned from the right query

**Intersect:-**
Returns any distinct values that are returned by both the query on the left and right sides of the INTERSECT operand.

Example:- Lets say we have two tables Table 1 and Table 2

```
Table_1 column name(Number, datatype int)
----------

1
2

3
4
5

Table_2 column name(Number, datatype int)
----------

1
2

5

SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM  TABLE_2
```

will return 3,4 as it is present in Table_1 not in Table_2

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM  TABLE_2
```

will return 1,2,5 as they are present in both tables Table_1 and Table_2.

All the pains of Complex joins are now eliminated :-)

To use this functionality in SSIS, all you need to do add an "Execute SQL" task and put the code in there.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to create an upsert in sql (if you have pre-stage or stage tables):

```
--Insert Portion
INSERT INTO FinalTable
( Colums )
SELECT T.TempColumns
FROM TempTable T
WHERE
(
    SELECT 'Bam'
    FROM FinalTable F
    WHERE F.Key(s) = T.Key(s)
) IS NULL

--Update Portion
UPDATE FinalTable
SET NonKeyColumn(s) = T.TempNonKeyColumn(s)
FROM TempTable T
WHERE FinalTable.Key(s) = T.Key(s)
    AND CHECKSUM(FinalTable.NonKeyColumn(s)) <> CHECKSUM(T.NonKeyColumn(s))
```

Comment: This is a good way to do it in SQL 2005, but don't forget the optional 3rd section for deleting data.  However, SQL Server 2008 has the MERGE statement with similar functionality and is probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to let SSIS engine to manage delta merge. Only new items are inserted and changed are updated.
If your destination Server does not have enough resources to manage heavy query, this method allow to use resources of your SSIS server.

Answer (score 0):

1. We can use slowly changing dimension component in SSIS to upsert.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/configure-outputs-using-the-slowly-changing-dimension-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

I would use the 'slow changing dimension' task