# Incremental Loads in SSIS

Tags: ssis

i have an input csv file with columns position_Id, Asofdate, etc  which has to be loaded into staging table. In my table, columns Position_Id, AsofDate are primary keys. We receive this input file for very 2 hours. For Exmaple, we recived File at 10 Am today, and that files loads into table.And after 2 more hours we recived another file whcih contains of same data as of the file which we recived 2 hours back and data loads into table.

```
Now my table contains the data of the file that we recived at 10 Am and 12 pm. At 12:10 pm we received modified input file with different data inside it. Now, my actual requirement is, before the latest input file (12:10 Pm) data is loaded int table, it has to see that only new and updated data has to be loaded into the table.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever heard of the term `Upsert`?  Here are examples of how to upsert (insert new records and update existing records).

1. This [blog post](http://rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/46-SSIS-Upsert-With-Lookup-Transform.html) walks you through Upserting using a lookup in a dataflow.
2. This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134675/390679) provides links to explaining and setting up a merge.